# Service Basics problems

Tags: android

I want to understand something in a service... 
My question is this :

if i call a service from BroadcastReceiver by :

```
 startService()
```

say for example MyService.class

so inside of that is it possible to this:

```
int i=0;
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // The service is starting, due to a call to startService()


         if(i>10)
{
        stopSelf().
}
       else{
         i++;
    }
}
```

So if i understood correctly the service will run onStartCommand untill he will get i>10 then it will destroy?

Comment: I think you should keep i=0 inside onStartCommand();

Comment: assume that im getting the i from the broadcast receiver.. is it possible the i will get increase like a loop here untill the service will stop ?

Comment: ya it will work, sorry, it was my misunderstanding

Comment: So the onStartCommand() is basically like a infinite while loop that stops only when it gets to stopSelf()???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest 
>       (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()

So, seems to be, yes the `i` will increase with each `onStartCommand` call

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: But im calling the service only once from BroadcastReceiver by startService() command ... it will stay in onStartCommand untill i>10 ?

Comment: So I dont get it... the service will never stop ?

Comment: The service stops as soon as stopSelf gets called.

Comment: But stopSelf will never get called again because im calling the service only once from broadcastreceiver.....